# running websockets along with grpc server?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, grpc

I'm trying to run two servers together to redirect data from one websckets server to another grpc and vice versa, but asyncio only starts one server. It is also not clear how data from events can be sent to the grps stream?

asyncio.geather, the first server specified by the first argument is started. How to make them work together and call websocket methods when receiving an event in grpc and vice versa

```
from concurrent import futures
import grpc
import timeseries_pb2
import timeseries_pb2_grpc
import pandas as pd
import asyncio
import logging

try:
    import websockets
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print("This example relies on the 'websockets' package.")
    print("Please install it by running: ")
    print()
    print(" $ pip install websockets")
    import sys

    sys.exit(1)

from ocpp.routing import on
from ocpp.v16 import ChargePoint as cp
from ocpp.v16 import call_result
from ocpp.v16.enums import Action, RegistrationStatus

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


class ChargePoint(cp):
    @on(Action.BootNotification)
    def on_boot_notification(
        self, charge_point_vendor: str, charge_point_model: str, **kwargs
    ):
        return call_result.BootNotificationPayload(
            current_time=datetime.utcnow().isoformat(),
            interval=10,
            status=RegistrationStatus.accepted,
        )


async def on_connect(websocket, path):
    try:
        requested_protocols = websocket.request_headers["Sec-WebSocket-Protocol"]
    except KeyError:
        logging.error("Client hasn't requested any Subprotocol. Closing Connection")
        return await websocket.close()
    if websocket.subprotocol:
        logging.info("Protocols Matched: %s", websocket.subprotocol)
    else:
        # In the websockets lib if no subprotocols are supported by the
        # client and the server, it proceeds without a subprotocol,
        # so we have to manually close the connection.
        logging.warning(
            "Protocols Mismatched | Expected Subprotocols: %s,"
            " but client supports  %s | Closing connection",
            websocket.available_subprotocols,
            requested_protocols,
        )
        return await websocket.close()

    charge_point_id = path.strip("/")
    cp = ChargePoint(charge_point_id, websocket)

    await cp.start()

class NiftyService(timeseries_pb2_grpc.NiftyServiceServicer):
    """The listener function implements the rpc call as described in the .proto file"""
    def __init__(self, port):
        print("server running on port %d" % (port, ))
        self.port = port
        self.data_frame = pd.read_csv("static/data.csv", low_memory=False)
        self.data_frame['timestamp'] = self.data_frame['Date'].apply(lambda x: int(pd.Timestamp(x).timestamp()))

    def NiftyCall(self, request, context):
        """
        Service method to filter daily close values for Nifty between dates provided in request
        request.startDate:
        request.endDate:
        """
        # Filter the dataframe as per the start and end timestamps
        filtered_df = self.data_frame[(self.data_frame.timestamp > request.startDate) &
                                      (self.data_frame.timestamp < request.endDate)]

        # Iterate through the filtered dataframe and yield the rows
        for _, row in filtered_df.iterrows():
            yield timeseries_pb2.NiftyResponse(date=row['timestamp'], value=row['Close'])


async def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    nifty_service = NiftyService(port=8010)
    timeseries_pb2_grpc.add_NiftyServiceServicer_to_server(nifty_service, server)
    server.add_insecure_port("0.0.0.0:%d" % (nifty_service.port, ))
    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()
    
    ws_server = await websockets.serve(
        on_connect, "0.0.0.0", 9000, subprotocols=["ocpp1.6"]
    )

    logging.info("Server Started listening to new connections...")

    await asyncio.gather(await server.wait_closed(),await ws_server.wait_closed())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # asyncio.run() is used when running this example with Python >= 3.7v
    asyncio.run(serve())


Output:
PS C:\Users\...\grpc-timeseries\server> python server.py
server running on port 8010
```